Why is the manual deploy using Render's deploy hooks and GitHub Actions failing?
I'm attempting to create a CI/CD pipeline using GitHub Actions and Render's manual deploy hooks. The deploy will trigger if tests pass and the master branch is affected, however, the actual curl request is failing with error "(3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL". I have the deploy hook URL saved to a repository secret on GitHub, and I'm referencing that secret in the GitHub Actions file - I think there's a breakdown there, where the URL isn't being read properly, but I checked my syntax against Render and GitHub's docs, and can't find the error.
Here is the code from my GitHub Actions file:
name: Deploy
      uses: actions/checkout@v4
      if: github.ref == 'refs/heads/master'
      env: 
        deploy_url: ${{ secrets.FRONTEND_DEPLOY_HOOK }}
    - run: curl "$env:deploy_url"

I tried grabbing the deploy hook again and saving over the original deploy hook secret value, to make sure the correct URL is being saved. I tried tweaking the syntax by adding the 'env:' that is found in the run command included above, but which is missing from the Render documentation but present in the GitHub docs (tried with and without). I tried various Google searches for similar problems. I haven't been able to find the solution.

$env: would be for a Windows runner (it's Powershell syntax), it's not clear if that's what you actually have. Can you give a [mre]? Does the curl work locally?

@jonrsharpe I haven't tried the curl locally, I'll give that a shot. As for the syntax, I did try without it initially - it failed using run: curl "$deploy_url"
